# Stripping non-alphanumeric chars but leaving spaces in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string

Trying to change this:

```
"The basketball-player is great! (Kobe Bryant)"
```

into this:

```
"the basketball player is great kobe bryant"
```

Want to downcase and remove all punctuation but leave spaces...

Tried `string.downcase.gsub(/[^a-z ]/, '')` but it removes the spaces

Comment: should you replace hyphens with spaces?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can simply add `\s` (whitespace)

`string.downcase.gsub(/[^a-z0-9\s]/i, '')`

Comment: Note: this will strip out numbers.

Comment: This makes `basketball-player` into `basketballplayer`

Comment: This is helpful! But I don't think we need the `/i` because we are already downcasing, right?

Comment: To be clear, we don't need `downcase` for this to work, right?

Comment: OP wanted to `downcase` which may or may not be your case. If you don't need to `downcase` you may need to adjust the regexp to allow for uppercase characters.

Answer (score 17):

If you want to catch non-latin characters, too:

```
str = "The basketball-player is great! (Kobe Bryant) (ひらがな)"
str.downcase.gsub(/[^[:word:]\s]/, '')
#=> "the basketballplayer is great kobe bryant ひらがな"
```

Answer (score 12):

Some fine solutions, but simplest is usually best:

```
string.downcase.gsub /\W+/, ' '
```

Answer (score 6):

All the other answers strip out numbers as well.  That works for the example given but doesn't really answer the question which is how to strip out **non-alphanumeric**.

```
string.downcase.gsub(/[^\w\s]/, '')
```

Note this will not strip out underscores.  If you need that then:

```
string.downcase.gsub(/[^a-zA-Z\s\d]/, '')
```

Comment: Thanks for accounting for retaining numbers. As a small suggestion, the `\w` already includes digits, so you can leave out `\d` in this regex.

Comment: good catch.  I updated the answer.  Also noticed it didn't handle underscores so added an alternative that will.

Answer (score 1):

`a.downcase.gsub(/[^a-z ]/, "")`

Note the whitespace I have added after a-z. 
Also if you want to replace all whitespaces(not only space use \s as proposed by gmalette).

Comment: `a.downcase.delete('^a-z ')` is an alternative.

Comment: Thanks Ivaylo and @steenslag, I liked this and it helped retain the spaces.

Answer (score 1):

All the previous answers make basketball-player into basketballplayer or remove numbers entirely, which is not exactly what is required.

The following code does exactly what you asked:

```
text.downcase
    .gsub(/[^[:word:]\s]/, ' ') # Replace sequences of non-alphanumerical chars by a single space
```

Hope this helps someone!